# If G is an abelian group of order $p^t m$, with $(p,m)=1$, prove that $G(p)$ has order $P^t$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is an abelian group of order $(p^t)m$, with $(p,m)=1$, prove that $G(p)$ has order $P^t$.

Could someone help me about this problem? Do we need to use Cauchy's thm?

Comment: What do you call " G(p) " to?...and how "we don't know G is a finite group" if we're given that its order is $\;p^tm\;$ ??

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, I made a stupid mistake, thanks for your remind!

Comment: ..and you didn't address my question...

Comment: @DonAntonio G(p) is the set of elements whose power is some order of p. Now,we know G has an element of order p.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Show that G(p) has prime power order $p^k$, where $k \leq t$.
2. If $k < t$, find a contradiction by applying Cauchy's theorem to $G/G(p)$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the first step because the order of G(p) divides the order of G, but I do not see the contradiction in second step.

Comment: In the first step you should also note that no other prime divides the order of $G(p)$ by Cauchy's theorem. For the second step, by Cauchy you would have a subgroup $H/G(p)$ of order $p$...